# How would I find if the series converges or diverges using the Direct Comparison Test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I do not understand the Direct Comparison test at all so I need a walk through, because I read the examples and none of it makes sense to me. Here we go, the problem reads:

Use the Direct Comparison Test to determine whether this series converges or diverges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n^2}{(n^3+1)^{1.01}}$$

I'm still uncertain on how I will break this up and etc. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac {n^2}{(n^3+1)^{1.01}}\sim \frac{n^2}{n^{3,03}}=\frac1{n^{1.03}}$$

Comment: Is it really that simple?

Comment: @Adan Vivero Yes it is, but more precisely $\frac {n^2}{(n^3+1)^{1.01}}< \frac{n^2}{n^{3,03}}=\frac1{n^{1.03}}$

Comment: Interesting, so I would assume this converges since it equals roughly to zero... correct?

Comment: It converges because $\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p > 1$ and diverges for $p \le 1$, which is a fact that is very useful to know when doing comparison tests.